# Can't resolve CORS error for credentialed request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, cors

I keep facing the CORS error when making a credentialed request (`withCredentials: true`). I have an httpproxy setup in express.js that routes to a couple of microservices that sit behind it (these are express.js apps as well). Here's the relevant code, let me know if I should provide any more context.

Request from frontend running on `http://localhost:3000/` (React.js + axios):

```
const response = await axios.post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:3030/register/",
        requestData
      );
```

Error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:3080/polls?user=64749d4793bfab3dc9946246. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://127.0.0.1:3000’)
```

These are the options I apply for the `http-proxy-middleware`:

```
import { createProxyMiddleware } from "http-proxy-middleware";
app.use('/polls', createProxyMiddleware({
            target: "http://localhost:3050",
            changeOrigin: true
        }))
```

Initially I had a wildcard set for the CORS origin option `{origin: "*"}`, but later found out from [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/572) that credentialed requests cannot use wildcards for the allowed origin header.

Enabling CORS in the "polls" app:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
}))
```

I've been banging my head over this for 4 hours now (new to setting up CORS), please help.

Comment: try
app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
  credentials: true,
})); in polls app

Comment: @Dawid doesn't seem to change anything. I also tried enabling CORS in the api-gateway (http-proxy), that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the http-proxy-middleware configuration, which could be causing the CORS error.
You can modify the http-proxy-middleware configuration to pass the relevant CORS headers from the target to the client. Try adding these options,

```
app.use('/polls', createProxyMiddleware({
  target: "http://localhost:3050",
  changeOrigin: true,
  onProxyRes: (proxyRes, req, res) => {
    // Set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to the requesting origin
    proxyRes.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'the-origin-url-goes-here'
    // Set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header to 'true'
    proxyRes.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
  },
}))
```

you should also ensure that your backend "polls" app sets the appropriate CORS configuration

```
 app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
  credentials: true
 }))
```

you can enable "trust proxy" using the trust proxy setting to tell Express.js to trust certain headers when making decisions about client IPs, protocol, and secure connections.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// Enable "trust proxy" 
app.set('trust proxy', true)

// Rest of your app configuration and routes
```

Hope this solve the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the proxy that is the problem. I tried to make the request directly to the `polls` app having `withCredentials: true` and got the same error.

A new bit of information I found is that in the error -  `does not match ‘http://127.0.0.1:3000’` . The address refers to the one I set for cors origin in the "polls" app. How does that make sense? Isn't the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header being set by the server (me) itself when I say `cors({origin: "http://127.0.0.1:3000"})? If yes, then how does the header not match when I'm the one who set the allowed origin?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Apparently I was fixing the cors issue on the server (I added `http://localhost:3000` along with `http://127.0.0.1:3000` to the allowed origins) correctly but had to refresh the browser for the cors edits in the backend to come into play.